# Using powershell, in a csv doc, need to iterate and insert a character

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

So my csv file looks something like:

```
J|T|W
J|T|W
J|T|W
```

I'd like to iterate through, most likely using a regex so that after the two pipes and content \|.+{2}, and insert a tab character `t.

I'm assuming I'd use get-content to loop through, but I'm unsure of where to go from there.

Also...just thought of this, it is possible that the line will overrun to the next line, and therefore the two pipes will be on different lines, which I'm pretty sure makes a difference.

-Thanks

Comment: Feel free to show the desired result. And also what would it be in the case of `A|B|C|D`?

Comment: the actual query is more complex, I have a variable storing the number of pipes needed, that would actually go between the curly braces depending on the csv, the main issue is adding the tab character after the last "|content", so in your case after the |D

Comment: So you want to add a tab after the last `|`? `s/\|(?=[^|]*$)/|\t/` this replace should do it then, however you write that in PowerShell.

Comment: problem is, I don't know how to do it in powershell! XD

Comment: Also is it a true CSV? You mention something about fields potentially having a newline in them?

Comment: It is a true csv, created by the export-csv cmdlet, the problem is that some fields are text fields, which do have carriage returns, but not tabs, so I am essentially trying to parse through a certain number of pipes, the number of columns, and after which insert a tab character, which we will use as the row end instead

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something simple. If it is a CSV, why do you need the regex to determine fields? Import-csv .\test.csv -Delimiter '|' -Header 'One', 'two', 'three' | %{$_.Three = "`t$($_.Three)"; $_} | Export-CSV .\test_result.cs

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't thought of this approach, however, I have two issues with it, the first being, I'm not going to have a header row, and the second being, I am dynamically parsing through a large number of csv's without knowing the number of columns, aside from pulling that number from a sql table dynamically.

Comment: You don't need to have a header row. That is what the -Header param is for. As for having a dynamic number of fields, As long as you know how many fields exist in the file then: -Header (1..$FieldCount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll move the comment discussion to an answer since it seems like it is a potentially valid solution:

```
 Import-csv .\test.csv -Delimiter '|' -Header 'One', 'two', 'three' | %{$_.Three = "`t$($_.Three)"; $_} | Export-CSV .\test_result.cs
```

This works for a file that is known to have 3 fields. For a more generic solution, if you have the ability to determine the number of fields initially being exported to CSV, then:

```
 Import-csv .\test.csv -Delimiter '|' -Header (1..$fieldCount) | %{$_.$fieldCount = "`t$($_.$fieldCount)"; $_} | Export-CSV .\test_result.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can use the `-replace` operator with a regex e.g.:

```
$c = Get-Content foo.csv | Foreach {$_ -replace '<regex_here>','new_string'}
$c | Out-File foo.csv -encoding ascii
```

Note that in `new_string` you can refer to capture groups using `$1` but you'll want to put that string in single quotes so PowerShell won't try to interpret `$1` as a variable reference.

Comment: well, yes, but I need to count a certain number of those groups, in my example 2, and after which I need to insert the tab character. Using your example, I'm assuming I could capture all the data before in a variable and then append the tab character to it, how would I do that?

Comment: for example, if this is the regex: \|.+{2}  How would I go about appending a tab after that? Also, does it matter if the pipes aren't all in the same line???

Comment: *IF* that regex captured everything you still wanted on that line then you'd do this `$_ -replace '(\|.{2})',"`$1`t"` but I can tell from the regex that it isn't capturing the entire line.  And if your rows actually span multiple lines then using Get-Content is a bust because it reads one line at a time and you would need the regex to work across multiple lines.  In this case, you either need to use Import-Csv (recommended) or you could read the entire CSV file as a single string and use a regex with a `(?sm)`directive.